# Powershell hanging in script

Tags: powershell, error-handling, certificate, freeze

I have written a script that will extract a large number of URLs from an excel spreadsheet and then make a web request and fetch the certificate information.

I am very new to powershell and have never worked to debug or process exception/error handling.

In my process there are certain points the script will just hang, no error is thrown and it does not terminate, just hangs for and indefinite period of time. Sometimes its a couple minutes other times a couple seconds.

I am trying to figure out if I can correct something in my code or if this hang is simply because of the servers I am contacting.

```
function GetCertificates($url) {
# // create a request
$req = [System.Net.WebRequest]::create($url)
$req.Method = "GET"
$req.Timeout = 600000 # = 10 minutes

# // set the proxy for connection
$proxy = New-Object System.Net.WebProxy "proxy.com:8000"
$req.Proxy = $proxy

# // Set if you need a username/password to access the resource
$Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
#$req.Credentials = New-Object Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
$req.Credentials = $Credentials

$req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT; Windows NT 6.1; en-US)"

try { 
    [Net.HttpWebResponse] $result = $req.GetResponse()
} 
catch {}

# // define the cert 
$cert = ''
$cert = $req.ServicePoint.Certificate

$httpstatuscode = [int]$result.StatusCode

try {
    [IO.Stream] $stream = $result.GetResponseStream()
    [IO.StreamReader] $reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader($stream)
    [string] $output = $reader.readToEnd()
    $stream.flush()
    $stream.close()
}
catch {}

# // write the results

Write-host $url
Write-host "Issued By : " $cert.Issuer
#Write-host "Subject : " $cert.Subject
#Write-host "Issued On : " $cert.GetEffectiveDateString()
#Write-host "Expires On : " $cert.GetExpirationDateString()
}

function GetExcel{
# // import the csv file
$xcel = import-csv C:\Users\Desktop\excel.csv

# // extract and run the URLs for only required TYPEs
$xcel | foreach{
    if
        ($_.TYPE -like "u_external_url" -or "qa_url" -or "u_load_balancing_url")
    {GetCertificates $_.URL}
    return $_.APP_ID
}
}
```

Comment: Try writing the `$Error` in your `catch{}` blocks. You might be leaving the `$stream` in an unusable state if there is an error.

Comment: May I ask why you are using `WebRequest` instead of `Invoke-WebRequest` or `Invoke-RestMethod`? It would simplify your code greatly

Comment: @MasonSchmidgall I just deleted my other two comments, I got the proxy to work with Invoke-WebRequest but how can I get the certificate information? I dont see the ServicePoint.Certificate method for the object that the WebRequest returns?

Comment: @MasonSchmidgall found a link but couldn't get it to work, posted a new question on it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57563946/trying-to-get-certificate-information-in-powershell